# Sticky Navbar with JS

Tags: javascript

Hello I have been trying to create a sticky navbar with vanilla javascript so when I scroll the logo. navbar would stay sticky, but wasn't successful because there are some errors which I wasn't able to fix them and i am asking for your help if someone can take a look at the code below and help me, thank you.

```js
let nav = document.querySelector('.nabar');
let topToNav = nav.offsetTop;
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');

function stickyNav () {
    if(window.scrollY >= topToNav) {
        logo.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
        logo.classList.add('fixed');
    } else {
        logo.style.paddingTop = 0;
        logo.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNav);
```

```css
.nabar{
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}
.nabar li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.nabar ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.nabar a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: white;
}
.nabar a{
  color: white;
}
.fixed .nabar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(black, .3);
}
.test{
  height: 600px;
  background: yellow;
  }
.test2{
  height: 609px;
  background: green;
  }
.logo{
  height: 100px;
}
.logoimg{
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
      <img class="logoimg" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/car_logo/car_logo_PNG1648.png">
    </div>
    <div class="nabar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="test">
        </div>
          <div class="test2">
        </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand well, you want to stick both **nav** and **logo** or just the **nav**?

Comment: nope only the nav, but after you scroll the logo then navbar would showoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your nav and logo to stick them both at thop like the code below

> in order to keep width of your nav use `position:sticky;` instead
>   of `position: fixed;`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {stickyNav()};
var mynavbar = document.getElementById("my-navbar");
var sticky = mynavbar.offsetTop;
function stickyNav() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    mynavbar.classList.add("fixed");
  } else {
    mynavbar.classList.remove("fixed");
  }
}
```

```css
.nabar{
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}
.nabar li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.nabar ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.nabar a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: white;
}
.nabar a{
  color: white;
}
.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(black, .3);
}
.test{
  height: 800px;
  background: yellow;
  }
.logo{
  height: 100px;
}
.logoimg{
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
```

```html
<div class="logo">
        <img class="logoimg" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/car_logo/car_logo_PNG1648.png">
  </div>

  <div id="my-navbar" class="nabar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

check on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZKgLe)

Comment: it's the same code as yours just i added a background color and a bit more height on .test and navbar stays sticky, but doesn't move at top and logo it stays still there when you scroll and navbar width when you scroll gets  larger.
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/jdzbOP

Answer (score 0):

The css .fixed .primary-nav with a space in between refers to this element:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="primary-nav" />
</div>
```

So the css below will not do anything in your context.

```
.fixed .primary-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(black, .3);
}
```

Take out the .primary-nav part, you don't even have an element with that class...

Comment: yeah i replaced .primary-nav with .nabar because that was supposed to refer .navbar but i did a mistake and replaced it but still sticky navbar doesn't work any idea?